Lost sudo. Beyond salvation?
I made a mistake and gave a container Homepage access to the docker.sock and briefly after I discovered that sudo is no more.
sudo
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

Am I beyond any salvation or what do you think?
Yes I've read almost every post I could find both here and on other forums and basically none of the suggestions work.
What I have not tried (yet) is doing an fresh install on some other drive, and then try to mount my system drive into that OS and maybe sort permissions through various commands and tools.. Thing is, I'm afraid of doing that cause even if I regain sudo abilities I don't really know what else has been done and maybe still is going on in/to my system since I guess through docker.sock my system has been and still is opened while I'm out.
Dose Linux based OS systems take logs of such actions?
Update, what I have tried:
pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
====AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ====
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/chown' as the super user
Authenticating as: ,,, (pi)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

pkexec visudo
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ====
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/sbin/visudo' as the super user
Authenticating as: ,,, (pi)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

chown root:root /etc/sudoers
chown: changing ownership of '/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted


What are all of the suggestions you tried, and what errors did they give? FYI fatrace & inotify could have logged all file changes, but your (r)syslog(d) could have logged something, at least to see what was running as root or sudo, possibly in an auth.log

Updated the post with some of the commands and the outputs based on various suggestions around forums on the internet.

hmmm, pkexec doesn't cooperate... have a root account set up with a password, tried su root? Or just boot from a live iso (from a usb or from the main drive, if editing grub works), mount & change the permissions that sudo requires

If your Docker daemon is still running, and you’ve got the appropriate privileges, you could mount your root file system in a subdirectory in a privileged container and fix things from there...

@StephenKitt, how would I go about that? Really far of my knowledge base but yeah, since this incident I haven't rebooted since I thought I would most likely lose access completely if I do.

Ok I tried something I found just now... In first terminal echo $$ got 593653 and in the second I ran pkttyagent --process 593653 back into the fist one and I could run pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R so the output of sudo is now different. Also I can run, pkexec visudo

Here are the commands and the steps, I sure hope this might help someone else if and when you would end up in my situation. However, you should not be so reckless and read previous answer here, which is informative and makes you causes moving forward.

Start two terminals and SSH into your machine.

In the first one run echo $$ make a note of that returned value.

In the second terminal, run
pkttyagent --process insert_value_here


Back to the first terminal and run pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R keep an eye on the second terminal and keep entering your user password each time it asked for it.

In the first terminal try using sudo, eg sudo fdisk -l or sudo -l if you can then nice, if you can't (I could not since some file was apparently missing) then go ahead and reinstall sudo using
pkexec apt-get purge sudo followed by pkexec apt-get install sudo
and then run (I had to) pkexec chown -R root:root /etc.


You are done.

Wow it is a sudo replacement? Good :-)

Sure it is, every time I use this new one it outputs a random page from The Linux Programming Bible: The Complete Guide to Learn Linux Commands, Linux Operating System and Shell Scripting Step-by-Step

A little bit more carefulness with docker would be surely very useful. Not because it would be soo insecure, but because often you need to give a lot of special access to the containers what they really do not deserve.
Without knowing more about that specific container(*), I think it is more like a misconfiguration as a security breach.
Now you have closed yourself out of your system.
There are various ways to get you back, note it is not huawei or apple where you had no access to your own system.
What you did: a fresh install to other drive, then mount your original root partition and fixing the permissions. That is a valid solution, although it might need more work as needed.
More power users are booting a live usb (or live cd), that does not need an installation and a new partition, to do the same. Of course it is not your friendly environment but you only need to do it once.
You can also get into a single-shell modus of most linuxes, although default installs tend to disable it. Give an init=/bin/bash argument to your boot loader. For more details, google for recover root password init=/bin/bash site:unix.stackexchange.com. That does not even need a live cd (usb).
On a home system, it is not so bad if you actually have a root password. So you can log in. By default it is blocked for anything (normally you can not create X sessions or remotely login with it).
Your system could be actually fixed by changing back the owner of your /etc/sudo* files by the command chown root:root -c /etc/sudo*. Possibly you will also need to use the chmod go-rwx -c /etc/sudo* to set up permissions correctly, although you did not hit this error yet.
*That is a feature of the docker. If you pick a randomly chosen container, probably no one will know about it anything. This is not like the well known Linux softwares and tools. Containers are coming from the cosmos and going to the cosmos back. You can only trust the containers what you made for yourself. So, do not give them docker sock access next time without a good reason.

Some lessons are learned the hard way... I'll go ahead and format and reinstall in the coming days. But now I can actually get what I need to get out of my system without live boot and no I have not sat a password for root and so I could not manage the boot loader road. But Im sure its valid and so your got an accept.
